# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error when running 2 different Specflow test in one Project

Tags: selenium, specflow, gherkin

I created a Nunit and specflow project and everything seem to work fine. But when I put everything relating to that testing in one folder and then created a new folder for another application in that same project with similar test steps as the original, I get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error. The error happens here:

```
_driver = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<IWebDriver>();
            ***if (!(_driver.Url.Equals(Constants.LandingPage)***))
            {
                _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Constants.LandingPage);
            }
```

When I do null check, `_driver` is returning null, which I don't understand why. Also whenever I exclude either the original test or the new one from the project, the remaining one seems to work fine. Please how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I have figured it out. In my BeforeFeature I had this code: FeatureContext.Current.Set<IWebDriver>(driver) and it is setting the driver to null. I commented it out the resolved the issue. That's weird. How do I close this?

Comment: BeforeFeature is called once for all scenarios in a feature file. If you want to do something for every scenario, you have to use the BeforeScenario hook.

Comment: What do you want to close?